# How can remove duplicate rows after execute a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I create this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM favorite_user_cellphone fc
WHERE user_id = 123 AND unfavorited_at is null
ORDER BY favorited_at DESC;
```

the result of this query is below:

```
favorite_id  | user_id |  cellphone_id |  favorited_at        |   unfavorited_at
     7           123         1225       2019-04-13 12:35:02     null
     5           123         1225       2019-04-11 12:35:02     null
     2           123         1275       2019-04-09 13:00:02     null
     1           123         1225       2019-04-09 12:35:02     null
```

But now I would like to remove the duplicate rows (column cellphone_id) and keep the row with the most current date for each cellphone_id

So, the final result should be like this:

```
favorite_id  | user_id |  cellphone_id |  favorited_at        |   unfavorited_at
     7           123         1225       2019-04-13 12:35:02     null
     2           123         1275       2019-04-09 13:00:02     null
```

I do it:

```
SELECT * FROM favorite_user_cellphone fc
WHERE user_id = 123 AND unfavorited_at is null
ORDER BY favorited_at DESC;
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: I would like know how to create the query my friend to get this information.

Comment: Postgres or MySQL?

Comment: Mysql my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, that you can run on your existing result table, might be:

```
select fuc.*
from favorite_user_cellphone fuc
inner join
(
   select cellphone_id, 
          max(favorite_id) as favorite_id
   from favorite_user_cellphone
   where user_id = 123
   group by cellphone_id
) t on fuc.favorite_id = t.favorite_id
```

Comment: It's working, but suppose that I need get the info from specifically user_id. this query get the rows from any user_id

Comment: @AndréRibeiro then you need a where clause, user_id = 123. Updated my answer

Comment: thank so much it's working.

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use aggreagtion function max() and group by

```
SELECT max(favorite_id), user_id cellphone_id, max(favorited_at)  
FROM favorite_user_cellphone fc
WHERE user_id = 123 AND unfavorited_at is null
GROUP BY cellphone_id, user_id 
ORDER BY favorited_at DESC;
```

if you use select * all the records are returned  also for info that can produce undesidered result  .. so you should select only the columns you need applying aggregation functio for reduce result